is there a difference between "circle up" and "circle around"?
Does "Circle up" suggest forming a circle with everyone facing inward, while "circle around" implies forming a circle with everyone facing outward.
I got it from a chatbot.
Is that correct?

"Circle around" is much more idiomatic with a single person's (or animal's) movement. "The boy circled around the tree, looking for a branch low enough for him to climb."

No, that's not correct at all.
Circle Up
Circle up means "form a circle." It is an instruction, often given by a leader to a group of people. The group will then form a circle with their bodies. This often means each person is standing shoulder to shoulder and facing inward, although in some cases they may be sitting or spaced further apart. Here are some examples with context:

A sports coach needs to give instructions to their team. They say "Okay, Team, circle up."
A teacher needs to gather their students from the lunch room so that the students can be counted. The teacher says "Class, circle up."

Circle up can also (more rarely) be used figuratively to describe communicating information to make sure someone knows what is happening on a specific topic. This is mostly used in business contexts and is synonymous with other idioms like:

touch base
circle back
close the loop

Circle Around
Circle around is not a common stand-alone phrase. It has a variety of meanings, which you can read more about at the Free Dictionary. The most closely related meaning would be to physically form a circle around something or someone. That is, for a group to position their bodies such that they are standing in a ring around a central item or person. Alternatively, a group that has circled around might not be standing in a circle shape at all, but may instead be clustered around without rigid structure. The members of the group will likely be facing inward to the focus point. Here are some examples in context:

A group of children are playing a game that involves standing in a circle with one person in the middle. The middle child is leading the game and says "okay, make a circle around me!"

A tour guide is giving a tour of a museum. Their group has been spread throughout a room, looking at the exhibit at their own pace. Now, they need to come back together to hear about the next exhibit. The guide says "When you're ready, come circle around this display."


Circle Facing Outward
English does not have an idiom that instructs a group to form a circle and face outward. Instead, a group leader giving that instruction would simply say "Please form a circle facing outward."
